# How can multiple Threads write to the database by using the same connection in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that creates multiple threads, and i need that any one of them will write to the DB. the problem is that if i use the same connection the data is incorrect due to the access of multiple threads to the same Variables (like statment.setString()).
if i use different connection it Takes all the benefit from the threads.
In summary: i need that all threads will access a class or another thread that will hold 1 connection and will hold a batch of queries and once in a while will perfome execute batch.
thank you!

Comment: What benefits you lose using multiple connections?

Comment: well I think with connection pooling you would make your life easier. If you have doubts about performance: Just set the minimum of open connection to 1 (or 0).

Comment: As a matter of fact the level of optimization your seeking here all depends on what your loading from db ... Small Json /XML objects or long bursts of serialised data ?? Also it depends on how you will Parse the data, do you have a static parser hangingaaround or do you initialize as needed ??? How long does it take for that to happen ?? Why do you even need batch execution ?? These questions will help you get better answer

Comment: You don't need pooling by default. The cheapest way is imo to tunnel statement execution through a singleton using synchronized methods (yes, I know, that is not elegant, but it works). A connection pool with the size of 1 might lead You - depending on the "spagheticity" of the code - into a consumer-producer-issue (A has conn, waits for B, B needs conn, held by A). With synchronized statements, You won't be struck by that problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point in doing this but if you want to do it anyway, then I suggest you synchronize the access to the DB through this connection. Add some common LOCK object and do this:

```
synchronized(LOCK){
    // use connection by current thread including
    // sensitive operations which
    // need this synchronization
}
```

But then note that even though you're using multiple threads they will wait on each other, i.e. their access to the DB through this connection will be serialized (not simultaneous).

Comment: It's ok, but I think he doesn't need to manage a new common LOCK object. Use `synchronized(connection)` instead.

Comment: @BrunoCandidoVolpatodaCunha Correct, that would probably also work. But I think it's cleaner if you use explicit final objects for locks and you use them just for this. This IMHO helps when maintaining complex code of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are describing (many threads accessing to a DB) is exactly what is current in web application. And the recommended practice is to set a pool of connections to mitigate between the contention that would arise with one single connection and the resource consumption with one connection per thread. Apache DBCP is one example of such connection pool.

Answer (score -1):

In the event that you just cant initialize more than one connection, in your connection class add a boolean flag called bound, a single thread cannot use the connection "if(bound)" ... any thread using the connection shall clear the flag upon done ... add while loop in each thread to check the flag until it gets false, then sets it true and starts using it ... quite easy ... u could also create a 4th dedicated synchronous thread for all network com that accepts tasks from other threads in a queue and executes them synchronously so nothing gets messed up ... anyway there is a million ways around this , choose which ever more appropriate for your application

Comment: No no no no, don't do this! Use locks instead. Using a boolean like this is a very poor substitute for using locks. It's subject to race conditions (two threads can read `bound` as `true` at the same time, and both proceed into the `if` statement), and the `while` loops you describe will chew up serious processing power. Don't do it!

Comment: Your are absolutely right, I am just suggesting the concept of reservation and rest waiting .... whether it be using locks or any other way, or even a very very simple boolean and polling it. It's just to show an idea, but the implementation could vary greatly. Personally I won't use the lock or the boolean, I would make a thread with a task queue and other threads keep adding to the queue and getting notification upon response arrival. That's the way he can achieve "batch operations"